# How to implement a throttle-like function but without loosing time between calls

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

I would like to implement a helper function like lodash's throttle, but which calls the passed callback only if the last call ended (and if not, delays the new call until then), instead of having a rule like "one call every x milliseconds".

What's the best approach here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So What you eventually want is to queue your function calls and call them from the stack.

```js
// keep a stack of inputs for the function calls
var stack = [], 
    timer = null;

function process() {
    var item = stack.shift();
    //
    // process the item here
    //
    if (stack.length === 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
}
// every time you call the function on event. instead of calling the processing function
// call this to add it in a queue
function queue(item) {
    stack.push(item);
    if (timer === null) {
        timer = setInterval(process, 500);
    }
}
```

You can make this function work for multiple types of calls too. 
    // use item as a deciding factor

```js
// keep a stack of inputs for the function calls
var stack = [],
  timer = null;
function reset(item){
    // reset item here
}
function process() {
  var item = stack.shift();
  //
  // process the item here
  //
  switch (item.call) {
    case 'reset':
         reset(item);
      break;
    case 'stop':
//         stop(item);
      break;
    default:
      // code block
      // deal with it
  }
  if (stack.length === 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
  }
}
// every time you call the function on event. instead of calling the processing function
// call this to add it in a queue
// for hybrid calls 
// use item = {'call': 'reset', 'data': item}
function queue(item) {
  stack.push(item);
  if (timer === null) {
    timer = setInterval(process, 500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem with that is the use of setInterval, I would like the next item to be processed as soon as the previous is done, in a non-blocking manner for the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

try using boolean variable like

```
var running = false;
```

use `setInterval` or similar function and put condition `if(!running){}` for statements to be performed. if statement is going to run then make `running = true`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked out a way :

```js
class Scheduler {
  private readonly stack: Function[] = [];

  private enqueue(task: Function) {
    if (this.stack.length < 2) this.stack.push(task);
    else this.stack[1] = task;
  }

  private dequeue() {
    if (this.stack.length) {
      const task = this.stack.shift()!;
      task();
      defer(() => this.dequeue());
    }
  }

  run(task: Function) {
    this.enqueue(task);
    defer(() => this.dequeue());
  }
}

// Usage :

const scheduler = new Scheduler()

// Very frequent call :

scheduler.run(() => { /* your heavy task */ })
```